# Stacks of Cards overlapping each other with different groups using Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

So, I have this design I'm trying to replicated on Xamarin Forms.
For example, a user has three portfolio, each portfolio contains a list of item. and I want to display each portfolio one after another while still giving the user a view that each portfolio has multiple item. So, the expected behaviour is that when a user clicks on each portfolio, the items under each portfolio will drop down for the user to see while other portfolio remain the same (Note: you can only open one at a time, once you click portfolio A and its items drop down, the currently opened portfolio will pack up).

Here is my question, How do I achieve this, how can i make the cards overlay each others overlaps.

below is the image sample of what i want to achieve

[image]

P.S: my plan is to achieve a stack of cards such that when clicked on, it will drop down and show the list of others. then when I click on another stack, the currently opened stack will close.

Comment: you asked this yesterday and it was closed.  Please don't post duplicates.

Comment: the reason was because i didnt explain explicitly. but I do need an answer please.